# Artifactory rpm install started but console webapp not working

Tags: tomcat, artifactory

I have installed a local Artifactory repository (open source version) using RPM install method on a RHEL virtual machine.

I try accessing its console from a browser on a client PC at:

http://myhost:8081/artifactory

It takes a long time and then times out:

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

When I do wget on the same server for http://myhost:8081/artifactory I get a response that looks like the UI for the console.

I can ssh from the client machine to the server just fine so hostname is resolvable.

So it looks like installation was successful but I do not know what else could be the problem that prevents access from my client PC. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the firewall on the artifactory server was the issue. When I disabled the firewall using:

```
service firewalld stop
```

then UI console started working.